# Networking errors causing vagrant machine not to start up

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-provision

I ran into the following error when I execute "vagrant up" command.

*The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network!
This will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change
the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of
a bridged or non-hostonly network.*

Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |o|
o.vm.box="centos/7"
o.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.13"
o.vm.provision "shell", :path=>"setup.sh"
end
```

setup.sh:

```
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y install vim,git,gedit,nmap
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Nothing is started but I see a machine in Virtual box and I double click and I start as usual. Could assign static IP but no network to outside world. Not sure where the things are going wrong.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've seen that particular error before. However I do have some Vagrant (VirtualBox) VMs that use both a private network to talk to each other, and NAT to talk to the wider world.

I make sure these don't conflict by specifying different private IPv4 network ranges for each. For example:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    # host-only interface address
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.0.2"

    # NAT interface address range
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natnet1", "172.16.0.0/12"]
    end
end
```